# Generates a 0 kb .tflite file while using tensorflow-lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-lite, toco

I have followed [this](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) website to get a customized object classifier. From this, I got the frozen inference graph, saved model, checkpoints and all the necessary data. Now I want to generate a .tflite file from this model to deploy it in android studio. For this I followed [this](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193) website and used the code below. This gave me a detect.tflite file with no errors. But the file is empty (0kb). I also tried the same code using the sample frozen graphs provided by the [website](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-a-realtime-mobile-object-detector-in-30-minutes-with-cloud-tpus-b78971cf1193). But the result was same. Is it because I am using windows 10 instead of Ubuntu ?

I also tried toco build and tflite_convert, but nothing works. Also can I use a CPU to create a .tflite file from a tensorflow model which is trained using GPU ?

```
    bazel run -c opt tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_tflite_graph.pb --output_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_detect.tflite --input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_values=128 --change_concat_input_ranges=false --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6 --allow_custom_ops

(tensorflow1) C:\Users\devim\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\tensorflow>bazel run tensorflow/lite/toco:toco --
--input_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_tflite_graph.pb
--output_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_detect.tflite
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 --input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'
--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 --mean_values=128 --std_values=128 --change_concat_input_ranges=false --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=6 --allow_custom_ops DEBUG: C:/users/devim/_bazel_devim/l7g3ilsc/external/build_bazel_rules_apple/apple/repositories.bzl:35:5: WARNING: `build_bazel_rules_apple` depends on `bazel_skylib` loaded from https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib.git (tag 0.6.0), but we have detected it already loaded into your workspace from None (tag None). You may run into compatibility issues. To silence this warning, pass `ignore_version_differences = True` to `apple_rules_dependencies()`.

INFO: Analysed target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured). INFO: Found 1 target... Target //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco up-to-date:   C:/users/devim/_bazel_devim/l7g3ilsc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco.exe INFO: Elapsed time: 8.960s, Critical Path: 0.02s INFO: 0 processes. INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action INFO: Running command line: C:/users/devim/_bazel_devim/l7g3ilsc/execroot/org_tensorflow/bazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/tensorflow/lite/toco/toco.exe '--input_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_tflite_graph.pb' '--output_file=C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/sample_detect.tflite' '--input_shapes=1,300,300,3' '--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor' '--output_arrays='\''TFLite_Detection_PostProcess'\'','\''TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1'\'','\''TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2'\'','\''TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'\''' '--inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8' '--mean_values=128' '--std_values=128' '--change_concat_input_ranges=false' '--defaulINFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action 2019-06-24 12:50:15.427241: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1335] Converting unsupported operation: TFLite_Detection_PostProcess 2019-06-24 12:50:15.444580: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1384] Unable to determine output type for op: TFLite_Detection_PostProcess 2019-06-24 12:50:15.505002: F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:912] Check failed: GetOpWithOutput(model, output_array) Specified output array "'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess'" is not produced by any op in this graph. Is it a typo? To silence this message, pass this flag:  allow_nonexistent_arrays
```

Comment: Please specify `--allow_custom_ops`.

Answer (score 1):

When encountering issues like generating a 0Kb "**.tflite**" file while using TensorFlow Lite, several factors could be causing the problem. The main issues that can be considered are:

- **Invalid Input Data:** Ensure that your input data is correctly formatted based in TensorFlow Lite's input requirement
- File Permission: Ensure that you have necessary permission to write the directory where you're trying to save "**.tflite**" file
- Model Optimisation
- Also check for error or any other kinds of warning
- Try a minimal example
- Ensure that you've downloaded all the dependencies